# Detect page change with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to detect what page i am being redirected to using javascript.

```
$(window).on("onbeforeunload",()=>{
    alert("Something")
})
```

This code never executes (despite me reloading the page or clicking on other URLs). I am running my scripts on localhost. Also, i would like to know the URL of the page that i am being redirected to.

This is my full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Practice</title>
         <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <script>
        $(window).unload(()=>{
            alert("Something");
        })

    </script>
    <a href = "http:\\www.youtube.com">Link</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The event name is just `beforeunload` not `onbeforeunload`. But you're not allowed to call `alert()` during this, it should just return a string.

Comment: Is there any way of detecting what URL i am being redirected to?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can `alert()` or do whatever you want and then redirect to the `url` like the following example?

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let url = this.href;
  alert(`You're leaving this page, would be redirected to : ${url}`)
  window.location.href = url;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href = "https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve">Link1</a>
<a href = "https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions">Link2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers(IE8+, FF3.6+, Chrome), you can just listen to the `hashchange` event on window.

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
  alert("The browser supports the hashchange event!");
}
function locationHashChanged() {
  if (location.hash === "#somecoolfeature") {
    somecoolfeature();
  }
}
window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```